# Some packages in Latex like fullpage, color or graphicx etc. don't work

Tags: latex, tex-live

I'm currently working on some Latex assignments. I use the Latex live distribution. I was being told that all the packages I need I would be able to get from there, however i wouldn't be writing this if that was the case.
Code's that have those packages don't compile. Obviously i trief tlgmr install fullpage... that didn't work.

As an example:
Here is the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{color}



% Define the colors
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.2, 0.6, 0.8}   % Blue
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.8, 0.2, 0.4}   % Red
\definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.4, 0.6, 0.2}   % Green

% Create the txt files
\newwrite\fileA
\newwrite\fileB
\newwrite\fileC
\immediate\openout\fileA=color1.txt
\immediate\openout\fileB=color2.txt
\immediate\openout\fileC=color3.txt
\immediate\write\fileA{[0.2, 0.6, 0.8]}
\immediate\write\fileB{[0.8, 0.2, 0.4]}
\immediate\write\fileC{[0.4, 0.6, 0.2]}
\immediate\closeout\fileA
\immediate\closeout\fileB
\immediate\closeout\fileC



\begin{document}





The colors are:
\begin{itemize}
  \item \textcolor{mycolor1}{Color 1}
  \item \input{color1.txt} Blue
  \item \textcolor{mycolor2}{Color 2}
  \item \input{color2.txt} Red
  \item \textcolor{mycolor3}{Color 3}
  \item \input{color3.txt} Green
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

this is what the compiler says:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.6.12)  16 JUN 2023 12:12
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**vierte.tex
(./vierte.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-06-05>
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen141
\Gin@req@width=\dimen142
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\@emptytoks=\toks18
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2023/05/13 v2.17o AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip50

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks19
\ex@=\dimen143
))
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen144
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count193
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count194
\leftroot@=\count195
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 410.
\classnum@=\count196
\DOTSCASE@=\count197
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box51
\strutbox@=\box52
LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 722.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 723.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 724.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 725.
\big@size=\dimen145
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count198
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 905.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 910.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 940.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 970.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 971.
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count199
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count266
\dspbrk@lvl=\count267
\tag@help=\toks20
\row@=\count268
\column@=\count269
\maxfields@=\count270
\andhelp@=\toks21
\eqnshift@=\dimen146
\alignsep@=\dimen147
\tagshift@=\dimen148
\tagwidth@=\dimen149
\totwidth@=\dimen150
\lineht@=\dimen151
\@envbody=\toks22
\multlinegap=\skip51
\multlinetaggap=\skip52
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks23
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2953.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954.
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
)

! LaTeX Error: File `fullpage.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.7 \usepackage
               {color}^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1866 strings out of 477695
 23562 string characters out of 5831861
 1851753 words of memory out of 5000000
 22406 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 513387 words of font info for 34 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 57i,0n,65p,222b,36s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I seriously don't know what to anymore. I tried´chat gpt the internet . I don't know how to resolve this.

Comment: It should be `tlmgr` not `tlgmr`. The bundle which contains fullpage is called `preprint`, so you should use `tlmgr install preprint` (you can look up the name to install in the "Contained in" section of https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fullpage)